# How might I implement conditional grouping in a Select element using angular?

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I would like to know if I can include additional logic in angular ng-options attribute for a Select element.

In one case, I have a set of options that are flat and have no groupings associated with them.
In another, I have multiple options that may have the same description, however their Id's vary because they are each grouped into categories. Based on the data sent over, I would like to display them as either grouped or not grouped.

GROUPED:

```
<select ng-model="tcCtrl.SelectedItem" 
        ng-options="item.Id + ' - ' + item.Description 
                    group by item.GroupDescription 
                    for item in ctrl.Context.ItemList }"></select>
```

NOT GROUPED:

```
<select ng-model="tcCtrl.SelectedItem" 
        ng-options="item.Id + ' - ' + item.Description 
                    for item in ctrl.Context.ItemList }"></select>
```

CONDITIONALLY GROUPED ??

If at all possible, I would like to avoid have two separate instances of the select element, however I do no think that the parser for the ngSelectDirective really takes any conditional logic.

Thoughts at good ways to implement something like this?

UPDATE:
Here's how the suggested attempt looks...even without any of the 'logic' to build the string.

```
var optionStr = "item.Id for item in ctrl.Context.Items";
...<select ng-options="{{ ctrl.optionStr }}"></select>...
```

Problem is when I try binding it the binding doesn't seem to want to stick. If I take the same generated string and replace the {{ property }} then it works fine. I can even confirm in chrome that the string is being rendered in the mark-up.

UPDATE:
I have proven that the suggested method does work in a very sterile environment.
http://jsfiddle.net/xbws8r5h/

There must be something in my environment that is a variant.

Comment: Why are you trying to write `ctrl.optionStr`. If should be just `optionStr`. You define controller object in ng-controller, e.g. `<div ng-controller="MyCtrl"><select ... ></div>` all the bindings are resolved in the context of this controller. Read more e.g. [here](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp).

Comment: i am using ControllerAs syntax across my application...not relying directly on $scope...I have proved that it's not the problem as well as attempting to run $scope.$apply and there is still no change

Comment: Updated to include a fiddle of a working version. Problem is, my environment doesn't behave the same way...looking deeper.

Comment: Yeah, indeed it seems to be working on your fiddle. I'm afraid I can't help you why it isn't working in your environment. At least unless you somehow manage to recreate the problem on fiddle.

Comment: sure...totally understand...this will be the gateway question...will try to replicate the environment...it involves the resolution of an external API call...which could be the kicker

Comment: why not use `ng-repeat` if those options are that complex?

Comment: ng-repeat with grouping options would result in two nested repeats and I'd like to avoid it. this is probably a timing issue...

Answer (score 0):

Just generate your ng-options expression in JavaScript (controller). Depending of some conditional logic assign different expression.

For example:

```
<select ng-model="tcCtrl.SelectedItem" 
        ng-options="{{ selectOptions }}"></select>
```

And your controller might look like:

```
if(groupCondition){
  $scope.selectOptions = "item.Id + ' - ' + item.Description 
                group by item.GroupDescription 
                for workType in ctrl.Context.ItemList";
} else {
  $scope.selectOptions = "item.Id + ' - ' + item.Description for workType in ctrl.Context.ItemList";
}
```

Also, shouldn't expression be "... for **item** in ctrl.Context.ItemList" instead of workType in your case?

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23687681/713937) .

Comment: ha...yup...changed 'workType' --> item...didn't pull them all out

Comment: I can bind the string that is generated by my controller, but when I {{ stickThePropertyInBrackets }} the binding doesn't seem to work with the object reference