# Dynamically Load ng-options from API with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I would like to dynamically load select elements from an API request.

Here is my controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('tripCtrl', function($scope){

    //Call to API to get people
    $scope.people = [
                            {
                                "id": 1,
                                "name": "Joe Hamlet"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 2,
                                "name": "Mary Jane"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 3,
                                "name": "Tom Lee"
                            }
                         ];
    //Call to API to get the element to load
    $scope.selectElement = 
                            {
                                "Options": "person[dynamicValue] as person[dynamicDisplayName] for person in people",
                                "DisplayName": "name",
                                "Value": "id"
                            };


    //Dynamicly load properties
    $scope.dynamicValue = $scope.selectElement.DisplayName;
    $scope.dynamicDisplayName = $scope.selectElement.Value;


 });
```

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="selectedPerson" ng-options="{{selectElement.Options}}">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
{{selectedPerson}}
```

I created a JSFiddle trying to accomplish this. http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/9493/

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687422/angularjs-dynamic-ng-options) which I was able to implement, but when I tried to set the ng-options from the Element's Options property, it failed to load. When inspected the HTML the code looks to be set properly, but the model binding isn't working.

Edit 12/28/2014:

After updating the Angular version in the original JS Fiddle, it worked properly, however when I expanded to use an actually API, I found another issue with loading ng-options dynamically. Here is the more in depth JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zjFp4/330/

Also here is my updated controller. The dataService.getElement() calls a hard coded string, where as the dataService.getElementFromApi() calls the same exact string, just from json-generator (which is the mock API). When inspected the objects set from the API, everything is there, so it must be an issue with the binding in Angular. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
function tripCtrl($scope, dataService) {

//Call to API to get people
    dataService.getPeople().then(
        function (event) {                
            $scope.people = event;                            
        },
        function (s) { 
            console.log(s); }
        );

    //Call to API to get the element to load
    $scope.selectElement = dataService.getElement();


    dataService.getElementFromApi().then(
        function (event) {                
            $scope.apiElement = event; 
            $scope.dynamicValue = $scope.apiElement.Value;
            $scope.dynamicDisplayName = $scope.apiElement.DisplayName;
        },
        function (s) { 
            console.log(s); }
        );
```

}

Comment: Post your relevant code in the question always. And it is a typo and indeed marked as typo.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I made some edits. I hope it helps.

Comment: That is because you are using way too old version of angular. Upgrade it to 1.2 atleast. Example [try using this version](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js) and see if it works.

Comment: Retracted my close vote after your clarification.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that it was using such an old version. You were correct, when I updated the version it worked, however when I expanded to use an actually API I ran into another issue where it isn't working. I will edit the question with the more in depth scenario.