# Ng-options not displaying anything

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I'm using this array on my controller:

```
var vm = this;
vm.documentGenerationEnum= [
            {id:0, name: 'Manual'},
            {id:1, name: 'Automatic'}
        ];
```

and I'm using this on the html

```
<select ng-model="vm.editable.DocumentGeneration"
  ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in vm.documentGenerationEnum"
class="product-field-input dropdown">
</select>
```

Though I'm getting an empty dropdown which make no sense to me. I'm pretty sure that the code is well done, because this is not a new topic for me. But I'm not sure what other things could cause this to occur, what other things could I consider?

Comment: Add <option> tags with ng for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs - dynamic ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687422/angularjs-dynamic-ng-options)

Answer (score 1):

Works fine in this example:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.editable = {};
    vm.documentGenerationEnum= [
        {id:0, name: 'Manual'},
        {id:1, name: 'Automatic'}
    ];
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
    <select ng-model="vm.editable.DocumentGeneration"
       ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in vm.documentGenerationEnum"
       class="product-field-input dropdown">
    </select>
    <br>Selection={{vm.editable.DocumentGeneration}}
</body>
```

Comment: weird, you got any idea what I could check that could cause this behavior on my app that I could check.